# How to solve $Ax=y$ according to minimal linear error?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-linear-algebra

I have an overconstrained problem $Ax = y$ that I’m solving for x with a least squares solver (eigen library).

I would like to have the problem solved however such that not the sum of squared errors is minimized, but the sum of errors.

Is there a way to modify the original problem so that I can still use my least-squares solver to solve for x?

If not, what algorithms can solve for that?

Comment: Did you search for l1 regression?

Comment: @lhf i’m fitting the coefficients of a superposition of orthogonal functions to datapoints that contain normal distributed noise. I want to ‘average’ that noise while solving - squared error makes outliers skew the result too much

Comment: Minimizing the sum of the absolute errors is a [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) problem. There exists a large body of work on solving them efficiently, but it will generally be more challenging then least squares.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments mentions you want to look into L1 regression but first give yourself some time to thinkt if that would make sense for your problem, maybe explaint why you would want to use L1.

Comment: I want to use L1 because my datapoints contain noise and I want to ‘average’ that noise. The elements of x are coefficients for orthonormalized functions

Comment: Again it is much more convient to solve $A^TAx=A^Ty$, while this will not give you the average error you might just want to calculate that afterwards.

Comment: I’m not interested in the average error but in the solution that minimizes the average error

Comment: As this problem does not yield a continous functional is to e solved iteratively

Comment: As my reputation does not let me comment on the answer below I must comment here, the answer below is plain wrong! To see that just look at the definition of the 2-norm (euclidean norm) even if we take away the sqrt it still is quadratic and as he said also convex but this is not l1 reg. !

Answer (score -1):

If you're using MATLAB or Python with a convex solver such as CVX you shouldn't have any problem. Instead of solving $$\min_\mathbf{x}\,\|A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|_2^2 $$ just solve the problem $$\min_\mathbf{x}\,\|A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|_2 $$ which is still a convex program. Convergence will be slower than the squared version, but it's still a problem that can be efficiently solved.